# How to replicate attribute data for all lines in GoodData table report?

Tags: attributes, report, repeat, gooddata

I'm working on a table report where the client needs all lines fulfilled with data, with no blank spaces.

[image]

We need the Date information, for example, to be repeated for each metric line. And so the Number, Week Day, and Store.

This can be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grouping of attribute values happens automatically and it is there to make reports easy to read. There is not a functionality to repeat attributes values in reports. So, it cannot be made in the report.

Attribute values are repeated, if report is exported to CSV file.

You can try to redesign the report to avoid the grouping.